# How to convert string back to list using Pandas

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, char

I have a txt file with some data and one of the columns is like this:

```
['BONGO', 'TOZZO', 'FALLO', 'PINCO']
```

In order to load the file I use the pandas function `to_csv`.

Once the dataframe is loaded it looks like the content is ok but then I realize that the item within the dataframe is not a list of items but a string whose elements are the characters of the list!

`df['column']` returns a string like this

```
"['BONGO', 'TOZZO', 'FALLO', 'PINCO']"
```

instead of a list like this:

```
['BONGO', 'TOZZO', 'FALLO', 'PINCO']
```

Therefore if I type `df['column'][0]` I get `'['` instead of `BONGO`

What should I do in order to transform the string back to its original list format? Is there any input to the `to_csv` function that I should use?

Comment: `eval(df['column'])`?

Comment: @JohnGalt NO!!!

Comment: `eval` is Dangerous specially when you are reading from DataFrame which may be created by some other source @JohnGalt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` as :

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = "['BONGO', 'TOZZO', 'FALLO', 'PINCO']"
>>> print ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> ['BONGO', 'TOZZO', 'FALLO', 'PINCO']
```