# str encapsulated arrays to array with pandas

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas

I am working with a dataframe, that contains arrays. Upon `read_cvs`, pandas seems to be storing my vetors in `str` mode. Like this:

```
df['column'].iloc[3]
>>>'[50.6402809, 4.6667145]'

type(df['column'].iloc[3])
>>> str
```

How can I convert the entire column to array? Like so:

```
df['column'].iloc[3]
>>>[50.6402809, 4.6667145]

type(df['column'].iloc[3])
>>> array
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string back to list using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351499/how-to-convert-string-back-to-list-using-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want numpy arrays use lambda function with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and convert to arrays:

```
import ast

df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

And if need lists:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['column'] = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df['column']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ast` module to interpret the strings literally. However, this can be dangerous, especially when reading the data from a file or worse, online.

An alternative would be to parse the file directly using [`series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) functions:

```
In [19]: parsed = (
    ...:     df['column']
    ...:     .str.strip('[]')
    ...:     .str.split(', ', )
    ...:     .apply(lambda x: np.array(x).astype(float)))
    ...:

In [20]: parsed
Out[20]:
0    [0.45482146988492345, 0.40132331304489344]
1      [0.4820128044982769, 0.6930103661982894]
2      [0.15845986027370507, 0.825879918750825]
3      [0.08389109330674027, 0.031864037778777]
Name: column, dtype: object
```